# Compiling .scm files with MIT-SCHEME

Tags: compilation, mit-scheme

Well, I'm trying to compile this simple scheme code using the **"better"** scheme interpreter/compiler **MIT-SCHEME**:

*code.scm*:

```
(declare (usual-integrations))
(define (s x) (* x x))
(display (s 2))
```

What am I doing? I'm doing this:

```
DXHJ ~ mit-scheme
DXHJ ~ (cf "code.scm")

;Generating SCode for file: "s.scm" => "s.bin"... done
;Compiling file: "s.bin" => "s.com"... done
;Unspecified return value
```

Well, after that I can't run anything. How can I generate an *.out* file?

Comment: what do you Meen by run? If you want it to run as a standalone binary AFAIK mit-scheme does not produce that. code.com works as expected when you load it from  an repl.

Comment: I just don't understand the meaning of compilation on MIT-SCHEME.

Comment: It basically compiles the file so it loads, and executes faster. If you have both code.scm and code.com, when you type (load "code") in the repl, code.com will be loaded. Other than that, it means the same as for any other language.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just wanted run these programs without MIT-SCHEME like C or C++.

Comment: Well, Chicken scheme can compile to C, Also Bigloo and Gambit. There is a list here: http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-implementations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems mit-scheme cannot compile to native, stand-alone binaries. There are other implementations that can do this. For example, Chicken scheme, Bigloo and gambit.